# How to run a Twisted (python) program in MAC?

Tags: python, twisted

I have installed Twisted in my MAC.

```
   $ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import twisted
>>> twisted.__version__
'13.1.0'
>>> import OpenSSL
>>> import twisted.internet.ssl
>>> twisted.internet.ssl.SSL
<module 'OpenSSL.SSL' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/SSL.so'>
>>>
```

I have a test program named as `test.tac`

How can I run that in MAC?  Can i run that as python script?

p.s: Im totally new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's a Python Script than yes, you can run it on your MAC.

Also check the Twisted Documentation Page ?
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html

Comment: Do we really need twistd program installed in our machine? I just copied whole code in that tac file and created a test.py file and ran. I was able to access my localhost :8080 page

Comment: Yes if you need Twisted than it should be installed on your machine using pip or create a virtualenv and install it using pip